# Eulerian graph - can the starter vertex appear more than twice

Tags: graph-theory

I need to find an Eulerian circuit through a given graph, and I understand the laws pertaining to Eulerian graphs. I specifically am referring to the fact that the first vertex must be the same as the last ($x_0=x_f$).

I am wondering, however, if it is allowed for that starter vertex to be passed through between visiting it initially and finally.

Basically, is the first vertex allowed to be part of the eulerian circuit not just at the beginning and end. For example, first vertex is $1$ here. Can the circuit be: $C=(1,2,4,3,1,5,6,1)$ where $1$ appeared in the middle somewhere?

Comment: It seems that just each edge is supposed to be appeared once and vertices are allowed more than once!

Comment: So even the vertex 1 can appear more than twice?

Comment: yes! Also others can!

Answer (score 1):

In fact if you have an Eulerian graph $G$ (so every vertex is even) and you pick a vertex $v$ of degree $2k$, then any Eulerian circuit of $G$ will visit $v$ precisely $k$ times.

The reason is easy to see: when an Eulerian circuit enters and then leaves $v$, this "uses up" $2$ edges incident to $v$. Since you eventually need to use every edge incident to $v$ for the circuit to be Eulerian, you need to enter and leave $\deg(v)/2=k$ times.